# Universal instantiation and substitution

Tags: logic, quantification

I've recently read some of the article on first order logic from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderLogic.html and I'm puzzled by the explanation of universal instantiation that the author gives. It says

> the following rule holds provided that F(r) is the result of substituting variable  r for the free occurrences of x in sentential formula F and all occurrences of r resulting from this substitution are free in F,
>
> ```
> ∀x F(x) 
> -------
>   F(r)
> ```

I don't understand how F(r) is the result of substituting variable r for the free occurrences of x when x is bound by the universal quantifier. How exactly is x free?

Comment: F(r) is the result of subst the *term* **r** for the free occurrences of the variable **x** into F(x), and not (forall x F(x) ...). You can see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951074/is-replacing-y-by-x-formally-a-valid-substitution-in-the-formula-forall-x) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It says that (∀x)Fx ⇒ Fr

> where F(x) is any sentential formula in which x occurs free, r is a term, F(r) is the result of substituting r for the free occurrences of x in sentential formula F, and all occurrences of all variables in r are free in F.

Note that that way of putting it doesn't say that x is free in (∀x)F(x). It says that x is free in F(x) — in the sentence that the universal quantifier in question applies to. In other words, that substitution of r for that x works because that x is not bound in F by any other quantifier.